# What is the measure of $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{DEF} ~if~ \overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{ABC} =100^\circ$

Tags: geometry

For reference:(ANSWER: $100^\circ$

[image]

I couldn't identify much.. I only know that by property

$FH\parallel JA\\
\measuredangle AJC = 50^\circ$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already correctly determined that $\angle AJC=50$ (since an inscribed angle of a circle is equal to $1/2$ the measure of the arc it subtends). Since you have $FH \parallel JA$, you can use the fact that alternate interior angles (of two parallel lines intersected by a transversal) are congruent to prove that $\angle AJC \cong \angle DHF$, and so $m\angle DHF = 50$. Finally, since $\angle DHF$ is an inscribed angle and subtends arc $DEF$, the measure of arc $DEF$ will be twice the measure of $\angle DHF$, giving you the expected answer of $2*50 =$ **100**